# ScheduledExecutorService will execute irrespective of previous task completion status

Tags: java, scheduler

I am using `ScheduledExecutorService` where at times task may run for 3 hours to complete `pollMergeFiles.searchForFileAndExecute()` method and some times it may take less than 2 minutes to complete.

My only question is if `scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate` will end up executing every 10 minutes with a delay of 5 minutes or it will wait until previous task running to be completed and only then start new task?

```
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    ...
    PollMergeFiles pollMergeFiles = new PollMergeFiles();
    final Runnable service = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (counter <= 256) {
                    pollMergeFiles.searchForFileAndExecute();
                } else if (counter > 256) {
                    logger.info(
                            "Shutdown the scheduler service since all counters were processed");
                    scheduler.shutdown();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Exception found", e);
            }
        }
    };

    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(service, 5, 10, TimeUnit.Minutes);
```

Comment: scheduleAtFixedRate will start a new task every 10 minutes, scheduleWithFixedDelay will start a new task after 10 minutes when previous is finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the Java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html .

> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period,
> TimeUnit unit) Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes
> enabled first after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the
> given period; that is executions will commence after initialDelay then
> initialDelay+period, then initialDelay + 2 * period, and so on.

So scheduleAtFixedRate() won't wait for last task to finish. It will be executed at predefined interval (period field).

> scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long
> delay, TimeUnit unit) Creates and executes a periodic action that
> becomes enabled first after the given initial delay, and subsequently
> with the given delay between the termination of one execution and the
> commencement of the next.

But scheduleWithFixedDelay() method can wait for a predefined time (delay field)  after the last task is executed.